# Applying EmitDefaultValue to a property. How to specify the default value?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, attributes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WCF DataMember EmitDefaultValue on value type? (but set my own default value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253486/wcf-datamember-emitdefaultvalue-on-value-type-but-set-my-own-default-value)

Consider the following:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyType {
   [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = true)]
   public string MyStr = "DefVal";
}
```

In the code above, I can specify the default value to use after assignment.

Now consider the following:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyType {
   [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = true)]
   public string MyStr {
      get { ... }
      set { ... }
   }
}
```

How can I specify the default value here???

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

`EmitDefaultValue` says that if you do not specify the value it should still add element with default value for .NET type. In case of `string` it will be something like:

```
<MyStr xsi:nil="true" />
```

Your first example doesn't set default value. It sets common value because it is assignment as any other and if your incoming message contains `null` it will overwrite that initial value.

If you need any special value used instead of null (before serialization or after deserialization) use methods decorated with `[OnSerializing]` and `[OnDeserialized]` attributes as described in linked duplicate.